# pyqt4 programs, how to make installer for win

Tags: python, windows, pyqt

I've written an application in pyqt4. It is working in linux and i guess it should work in windows without any changes (there is nothing system specific). I'd like to make an installer for windows, so windows users doesn't have python and pyqt on their systems before.
So is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). It handles packaging for Windows, Linux and OS X. For an example of a packaged Qt4 application using PyInstaller, see [logview](http://code.google.com/p/logview/).